# Pending state stuck on EXTERNAL IP for Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I've tried to run this simple tutorial inside Google Container Engine which implements a simple guestbook [app](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook) using php and redis. 
The tutorial sounds so trivial. It contains two redis services of type Cluster IP -default kubernetes service type- and they are running so perfectly.

On the other hand, the third service is a front end service that is exposed publicly -outside the container cluster- with type --LoadBalancer.

i could run the service, but it should trigger an external LoadBalancer that will route external traffic to the pods of the container cluster, resulting in an External IP address. In the docs, they mention that it might take up to two minutes to get the service assigned with the LB external IP address. But i've waited for more than 20 minutes without luck.

```
NAME           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORTS          AGE
frontend       10.35.244.187    <pending>     80:31441/TCP   27m
kubernetes     10.35.240.1      <none>        443/TCP        1h
redis-master   10.35.248.31     <none>        6379/TCP       42m
redis-slave    10.35.250.172    <none>        6379/TCP       39m
```

What would cause such problem !! 
FYI: I've tried much simpler containerized app (a hello world Node.js app), the same issue appears to be happening there, Unfortunately.

Comment: Just be sure, do you use GCE or some other Kubernetes deployment?

Comment: @MaciekSawicki i don't have any other deployments. i have one GCE instance that is not operating inside GKE

Comment: Is is possible you've run out of a [quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) for a resource needed for a LoadBalancer? Check Target HTTP/S proxies, Target instances, Target pools. If so, just request an increase.

Comment: So you deployed K8 on GCE VM? What was your deployment method?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As @Janos Lenart suggested, it was a full quota issue. I was able to solve this by increasing my Forwarding rules quota in the GCP console.

Go to the GCP Console --> IAM and Admin (on the menu bar) --> Quotas --> Edit Quotas (in blue at the top of the page) --> Forwarding Rules

Although you need to submit a request I got an email telling me it'd been increased almost instantly. After that new load balancers got their external IPs assigned correctly.